# Is there a way to access the entire tibble/grouped tibble from the `mutate()` function acting on it?

Tags: r, dplyr

For example,

```
df1 = expand.grid(x1=1:2,x2=1:2,x3=1:2,x4=1:2,x5=1:2,x6=1:2) %>%
 mutate(
  x7 = sample(1:2,64,T), 
  y1 = rnorm(64)
 )

df2 = expand.grid(x1=1:2,x2=1:2,x3=1:2,x4=1:2,x5=1:2,x6=1:2) %>%
 mutate(
  x7 = sample(1:2,64,T), 
  y2 = rnorm(64)
 )

myfunc <- function(data){
    data %>%
     mutate(key = paste(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6)) %>%
     pull(key)
}

joined_df = df1 %>%
 mutate(y3 = runif(64)) %>%
 mutate(key=myfunc([some sort of expression referencing df1])) %>%
 inner_join(
  df2 %>%
   mutate(y4 = runif(64)) %>%
   mutate(key=myfunc([some sort of expression referencing df2]),
  by='key'
)
```

Essentially, I would like to *avoid* having to recreate the data frame from a function that looks like

```
myfunc_v2 <- function(data){
    data %>%
     mutate(key = paste(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6)) 
}
```

Even though `myfunc_v2()` is arguably cleaner, the main reason for this is that I usually change the names of variables using transformation functions like `rename_all()` across sources that are formatted differently, but do not want to actually modify them, in the main copy, as I am keeping the column name formatting from one of the tibbles and later discarding the others.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `df1 %>% unite(key, x1:x6)` from `tidyr`?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is straightforward.

When using the pipe operator `%>%`, which is how dplyr is usually used, you can specify where in the function it's acting on the argument should be used.

For a *copy* of the argument, all you need to do is to put `(.)` where you want the object, provided it's not inside of some anonymous function (e.g., with `mutate_all(data, list(scaled=~scale(.), signed=sign(.))`.

The solution would simply look like

```
joined_df = df1 %>%
 mutate(y3 = runif(64)) %>%
 mutate(key=myfunc((.)) %>%
 inner_join(
  df2 %>%
   mutate(y4 = runif(64)) %>%
   mutate(key=myfunc((.)),
  by='key'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @Max-Candocia works fine if you are using the magrittr pipe `%>%`, but not if you are using the native pipe `|>`. In that instance, you can use `pick(everything())` to reference the whole tibble (or a subset of columns with a tidyselect expression other than everything).

OP's code is broken, so here another example:

```r
library(dplyr)

iris |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  mutate(sum = pick(where(is.numeric)) |> 
           apply(1, sum)
           )
#> # A tibble: 150 × 6
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   sum
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa   10.2
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa    9.5
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa    9.4
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa    9.4
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa   10.2
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa   11.4
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa    9.7
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa   10.1
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa    8.9
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa    9.6
#> # ℹ 140 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-13 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>